# made outside header border in black background

Tags: html, css, border, background-color

I'm having a dead end here. I think it's suppose to be simple, but I've no idea how.

If you see this website header, http://effectiveadvisory.com/wingwah-may/ , I already made the border radius. Now, how do I want the outside border to be black?

This is the header div css.

```
header.header.main-header {
  border: 2px solid rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.2);
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

I tried putting out outline-style property with black color, but nothing happen.

Comment: Outside border means? do you mean, back side of the header should be black?

Comment: You want a second border that's black?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set parent background as black then set opaque background to the header. Like this :

```
.header-wrapper {
  background: black;
}

header.header.main-header {
  border: 2px solid rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.2);
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: Thx. Yeah guess this is the best option.